# Modify a device tree of qemuarm64 yocto image

Tags: yocto, qemu, arm64, device-tree

Is there a way to modify a device tree of qemuarm64 image?
I'm using an yocto to build it, but so far I can't find a source dts file which I can update with my modifications. Looks like that for qemu image it's using some built-in device tree which I can't find anywhere.

I've tried to modify foundation-v8.dtsi under arch/arm64/boot/arm, but it didn't have any effect. I assume, it just not used for qemuarm64 image.

Might be, there is another way to generate an image where I can modify device tree and be able to run as VM?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

QEMU creates device tree on the fly.

Assuming you have done the quick build Yocto instructions...

Dump the QEMU device tree:

```
$ runqemu qemuarm64 qemuparams="-machine dumpdtb=qemu.dtb"
```

Decompile the dumped device tree so you can edit it. I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and was able to install `dtc` with `sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler`.

```
$ dtc -I dtb -O dts qemu.dtb -o qemu.dts
```

Perform your edits, save & re-compile the device tree.

```
$ dtc -I dts -O dtb qemu.dts -o qemu2.dtb
```

Pass new device tree to QEMU when you run it next:

```
$ runqemu qemuarm64 qemuparams="-dtb qemu2.dtb"
```